# Scroll To H2 on every page

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is the best choice to create scrollTo function to every h2 on the page?
This is my code:

```
      <h2>First Chapter</h2> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu ante molestie dui vehicula finibus ac eget ante. Aliquam lacus mi,orci. Pellentesque nec lorem faucibus, tincidunt massa non, feugiat lacus. Pellentesque purus libero, efficitur ac finibus at, tincidunt vel ligula. Mauris consequat sit amet arcu in mollis. Quisque fermentum imperdiet justo dictum tempus. Curabitur elit tu </p>

<h2>Second Chapter</h2>
<p>Nam feugiat purus eu velit condimentum rhoncus. Proin pulvinar volutpat diam, id porta erat pharetra at. Mauris hendrerit nulla enim, et tempus urna placerat vitae. Integer ut ipsum tincidunt, sodales quam vitae, varius massa. Sed rhoncus arcu mi, in faucibus risus dictum vel. Cras id sollicitudin magna, quis tempor mi. In ultrices gravida quam, in scelerisque diam volutpat ac. Duis hendrerit tempu</p>

<h2>Third Chapter</h2>
<p> Nam feugiat purus eu velit condimentum rhoncus. Proin pulvinar volutpat diam, id porta erat pharetra at. Mauris hendrerit nulla enim, et tempus urna placerat vitae. Integer ut ipsum tincidunt, sodales quam vitae, varius massa. Sed rhoncus arcu mi, in faucibus risus dictum vel. Cras id sollicitudin magna, quis tempor mi. In ultrices gravida quam, in scelerisque diam volutpat ac. Duis hendrerit tempus dui, viverra euismod purus mattis</p>
<h2>Fourth Chapter</h2>
<p>Aenean et mi in nisi pellentesque porttitor pellentesque nec felis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer euismod mollis metus, nec fermentum ligula suscipit id. Nunc vitae gravida magna. Sed ut urna nunc. Fusce eget fringilla nulla, sed congue odio. Cras bibendum nisi est, quis scelerisque nisl laoreet non. Curabitur mi nibh, hendrerit</p>
```

I have 4 chapters (on this page) and I want to make scrollTo function to every of them. But on other of 10 pages will any chapters. Is there (in Javascript or jQuery) any simple function on it?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to do??? yes its possible, but for example,, what do you want to trigger the scroll?? a button? link?? would be very simple to write this function for you if you make a JSFiddle with what you have right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssbiswal1987/whha69uL/)

Take a look. This might help you.

```js
 $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
     if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

         var target = $(this.hash);
         target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
         if (target.length) {
             $('html,body').animate({
                 scrollTop: target.offset().top
             }, 1000);
             return false;
         }
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#1">First</a>  <a href="#2">Second</a>  <a href="#3">Third</a>  <a href="#4">Fourth</a> 

<h2 id="1">First Chapter</h2> 
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu ante molestie dui vehicula finibus ac eget ante. Aliquam lacus mi,orci. Pellentesque nec lorem faucibus, tincidunt massa non, feugiat lacus. Pellentesque purus libero, efficitur ac finibus at, tincidunt vel ligula. Mauris consequat sit amet arcu in mollis. Quisque fermentum imperdiet justo dictum tempus. Curabitur elit tu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu ante molestie dui vehicula finibus ac eget ante. Aliquam lacus mi,orci. Pellentesque nec lorem faucibus, tincidunt massa non, feugiat lacus. Pellentesque purus libero, efficitur ac finibus at, tincidunt vel ligula. Mauris consequat sit amet arcu in mollis. Quisque fermentum imperdiet justo dictum tempus. Curabitur elit tu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu ante molestie dui vehicula finibus ac eget ante. Aliquam lacus mi,orci. Pellentesque nec lorem faucibus, tincidunt massa non, feugiat lacus. Pellentesque purus libero, efficitur ac finibus at, tincidunt vel ligula. Mauris consequat sit amet arcu in mollis. Quisque fermentum imperdiet justo dictum tempus. Curabitur elit tu</p>

<h2 id="2">Second Chapter</h2>

<p>Nam feugiat purus eu velit condimentum rhoncus. Proin pulvinar volutpat diam, id porta erat pharetra at. Mauris hendrerit nulla enim, et tempus urna placerat vitae. Integer ut ipsum tincidunt, sodales quam vitae, varius massa. Sed rhoncus arcu mi, in faucibus risus dictum vel. Cras id sollicitudin magna, quis tempor mi. In ultrices gravida quam, in scelerisque diam volutpat ac. Duis hendrerit tempu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu ante molestie dui vehicula finibus ac eget ante. Aliquam lacus mi,orci. Pellentesque nec lorem faucibus, tincidunt massa non, feugiat lacus. Pellentesque purus libero, efficitur ac finibus at, tincidunt vel ligula. Mauris consequat sit amet arcu in mollis. Quisque fermentum imperdiet justo dictum tempus. Curabitur elit tu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu ante molestie dui vehicula finibus ac eget ante. Aliquam lacus mi,orci. Pellentesque nec lorem faucibus, tincidunt massa non, feugiat lacus. Pellentesque purus libero, efficitur ac finibus at, tincidunt vel ligula. Mauris consequat sit amet arcu in mollis. Quisque fermentum imperdiet justo dictum tempus. Curabitur elit tu</p>

<h2 id="3">Third Chapter</h2>

<p>Nam feugiat purus eu velit condimentum rhoncus. Proin pulvinar volutpat diam, id porta erat pharetra at. Mauris hendrerit nulla enim, et tempus urna placerat vitae. Integer ut ipsum tincidunt, sodales quam vitae, varius massa. Sed rhoncus arcu mi, in faucibus risus dictum vel. Cras id sollicitudin magna, quis tempor mi. In ultrices gravida quam, in scelerisque diam volutpat ac. Duis hendrerit tempus dui, viverra euismod purus mattis Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu ante molestie dui vehicula finibus ac eget ante. Aliquam lacus mi,orci. Pellentesque nec lorem faucibus, tincidunt massa non, feugiat lacus. Pellentesque purus libero, efficitur ac finibus at, tincidunt vel ligula. Mauris consequat sit amet arcu in mollis. Quisque fermentum imperdiet justo dictum tempus. Curabitur elit tu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu ante molestie dui vehicula finibus ac eget ante. Aliquam lacus mi,orci. Pellentesque nec lorem faucibus, tincidunt massa non, feugiat lacus. Pellentesque purus libero, efficitur ac finibus at, tincidunt vel ligula. Mauris consequat sit amet arcu in mollis. Quisque fermentum imperdiet justo dictum tempus. Curabitur elit tu</p>

<h2 id="4">Fourth Chapter</h2>

<p>Aenean et mi in nisi pellentesque porttitor pellentesque nec felis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer euismod mollis metus, nec fermentum ligula suscipit id. Nunc vitae gravida magna. Sed ut urna nunc. Fusce eget fringilla nulla, sed congue odio. Cras bibendum nisi est, quis scelerisque nisl laoreet non. Curabitur mi nibh, hendrerit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu ante molestie dui vehicula finibus ac eget ante. Aliquam lacus mi,orci. Pellentesque nec lorem faucibus, tincidunt massa non, feugiat lacus. Pellentesque purus libero, efficitur ac finibus at, tincidunt vel ligula. Mauris consequat sit amet arcu in mollis. Quisque fermentum imperdiet justo dictum tempus. Curabitur elit tu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu ante molestie dui vehicula finibus ac eget ante. Aliquam lacus mi,orci. Pellentesque nec lorem faucibus, tincidunt massa non, feugiat lacus. Pellentesque purus libero, efficitur ac finibus at, tincidunt vel ligula. Mauris consequat sit amet arcu in mollis. Quisque fermentum imperdiet justo dictum tempus. Curabitur elit tu</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="toc"></div>
  <h2>First Chapter</h2> 
  <p id=''>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu ante molestie dui vehicula finibus ac eget ante. Aliquam lacus mi,orci. Pellentesque nec lorem faucibus, tincidunt massa non, feugiat lacus. Pellentesque purus libero, efficitur ac finibus at, tincidunt vel ligula. Mauris consequat sit amet arcu in mollis. Quisque fermentum imperdiet justo dictum tempus. Curabitur elit tu </p>

  <h2>Second Chapter</h2>
  <p>Nam feugiat purus eu velit condimentum rhoncus. Proin pulvinar volutpat diam, id porta erat pharetra at. Mauris hendrerit nulla enim, et tempus urna placerat vitae. Integer ut ipsum tincidunt, sodales quam vitae, varius massa. Sed rhoncus arcu mi, in faucibus risus dictum vel. Cras id sollicitudin magna, quis tempor mi. In ultrices gravida quam, in scelerisque diam volutpat ac. Duis hendrerit tempu</p>

  <h2>Third Chapter</h2>
  <p> Nam feugiat purus eu velit condimentum rhoncus. Proin pulvinar volutpat diam, id porta erat pharetra at. Mauris hendrerit nulla enim, et tempus urna placerat vitae. Integer ut ipsum tincidunt, sodales quam vitae, varius massa. Sed rhoncus arcu mi, in faucibus risus dictum vel. Cras id sollicitudin magna, quis tempor mi. In ultrices gravida quam, in scelerisque diam volutpat ac. Duis hendrerit tempus dui, viverra euismod purus mattis</p>
  <h2>Fourth Chapter</h2>
  <p>Aenean et mi in nisi pellentesque porttitor pellentesque nec felis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In</p>
```

**JS**

```
$('<p/>', {
    'text': 'Table of contents'
}).appendTo('#toc');
$('<ol />').appendTo('#toc');
$('h2').each(
    function(i,el) {
        var $that = $(el),
            text = $that.text(),
            id = text.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/,'-');
        el.id = id;
        var a = $('<a />', {
            'href' : '#' + id,
            'text' : text
        }),
            li = $('<li />').append(a).appendTo('#toc ol');
    });
});
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h4hshxv5/5/)**